# RxJS - Same without Subscription / BehaviorSubject?

Tags: rxjs

I am looking for an alternate way to do :

```
import { interval, BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const source$ = interval(1000);
const store$ = new BehaviorSubject<number[]>([]);
source$.subscribe((point) => store$.next([...store$.value].concat(point)));

// result
store$.subscribe(console.log);
```

I indeed would like not to use subscription at all, and so I guess no BehaviorSubject.

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: So you would like to have a callback, that is called in every second?

Comment: I am more looking for a stream that will broadcast its last array plus a new one triggered by another stream (whatever the peace).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a scan operator.

```js
const source$ = interval(1000);
const store$ = source$.pipe( // or simply interval(1000).pipe(
    scan((result, value) => [...result, value], []),
);

// result
store$.subscribe(console.log); // [0], [0, 1], ...
```

Comment: Ok I see, this is a kind of reduce function, thanks !

Comment: yes, if you have several streams and want to aggregate them to a single array you can use `merge(stream1$, stream2$).pipe(...` and the same `scan` operator.